# Flutter- Firebase Phone Verification after register

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm developping a flutter app.
I have already created a Firebase project and I can register a user. I would like to do phone verification immediately after registering user with e-mail and password. I don't know how to do it. Anyone can guide me about that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you are in control of everything here, what you should do is after successfully registering a user, Navigate to the screen where you have the phone number verification process.

Then after that, you can log the user into the app.
The trick here is which screen to navigate to next.

Comment: yes you are right but there is no such function that IsPhoneVerified(). how can I handle that because I don't want to send sms every login. Should I add user's phone number to the user's collection in firebase?

Comment: You could mimic WhatsApp's login process, where by a logged in user is logged in always, using firebases persistence. Then that way the user only has to re-login whenever they clear their data from the device.